# solving a differential equation which I don't quite understand

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am just wondering how is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus being used here in this example:
[image]

It says in the last sentence: If $\xi \in J$ is fixed, then by the fundamental theorem of calculus, the function .... is a solution of the differential equation satisfying the initial condition $y(\xi)=0$.

I am just wondering which FTC is it using, is it FTC1, or FTC2? also how is the initial condition being used here to check if the solution satisfies $y(\xi)=0$?

could someone explains.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the form of the FTC that says that (with appropriate hypotheses) the derivative of a definite integral with respect to the upper limit of integration is the integrand.

So if
$$
g(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt  
$$
then
$$
g'(x) = f(x) \ .
$$

Clearly $g(a) = 0$.

Comment: Hi, I am just wondering if the initial condition is y(ξ)=7 or some other number, will the solution y(x) be different? if so, what will be the new solution y(x) if the initial condition is a number other than zero?

Comment: In the form you have asked the question the "initial condition" for the solution $g$ is the value of $x$ such that $g(x)=0$. It is more common to specify the initial condition as the value of $g$ at some particular $x$. To get that condition you add an appropriate number to the $g$ determined by an integral starting at $a$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it now.